# Filter() function randomly stops returning results

Tags: google-sheets

I've been having a reoccurring issue with Google Sheets. My FILTER() functions will randomly stop returning results instead saying:

> No Matches Are Found in FILTER Evaluation

I have to copy the function, delete the cell, then paste it back in for it to work right again. This will affect every sheet on my spreadsheet at once and it does not resolve itself, I have to manually reset each and every function (when you have thousands this is not maintainable).

After I fix the functions, they will work as expected on my view, but any other viewers of the spreadsheet still see the same error unless they also copy/delete/paste the function back in as well.

How do I fix this?

Note: Not posting my functions in here because it is not function specific, just every single FILTER() stops returning results, regardless of how simple it is.

Comment: This sort of thing may happen when your spreadsheet grows large enough that computations take longer than Google is willing to let them run. Consider splitting the task into separate spreadsheets with `importrange` to pull results from other spreadsheets.